# Can't deploy a dtsx package in file system - VS 2019 Community, SSDT

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to do a small test SSIS project - just one dtsx package that imports some data from an Excel file. I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 Community and a SQL Server 2016 developer instance installed locally. I've also installed the Integration Services component from the VS marketplace.
I'd like to deploy the SSIS package on the file system. But I cannot choose the path in the Integration Services Deployment Wizard (Select Destination), the Browse button is "grey" and I can't click on it.
Could anyone tell me if something is wrong and how can I deploy the package as a file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **Server Name** - localhost in your case, and hit **Connect** button. Then you can select path within SSIS Catalog where you deploy the package.